# ajax request python array list

Tags: python, arrays, request

I am making ajax call and fetching details in python and saving it in mongodb.

**Scenario:**
I tried `request.POST.getlist('arrayList[]')`

> *Works:* if array contains values inside it. Eg: ['abcd', '1234']
>
> ***Doesn't work:*** if array contains arrays inside it. Eg: [[arr1], [arr2]] -> this returns []

**How to retrieve outer array and inner arrays?**

Comment: Post equal to dict and dict values are string ! Post your data as string and use with `ast.literal_eval(form[key].value)`. Can post anyting as string(ajax object are different with python).

Comment: And a little tricks: Always convert to `Base64` before sending. Reach freedom !

Comment: @dsgdfg thanks,is there any other way to do this? coz `request.POST.getlist(arrayList[1][])` returns the one array inside it.
 Also, what you told completely went above from my head. Never did those things before.

Comment: @dsgdfg can you give a sample code for how it will be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution of my own. I will go through everything once again.

**Scenario:** *I am saving data from html in mongodb through python (django). There is a scenario where I have a single array and this array can have n number of smaller arrays inside and the smaller arrays can again have n numbers of smaller arrays and so on. I thought of doing it in my ajax request but I was new to python and wanted to learn the python way.*

I have attached image for reference as you can observer what I was talking about

[image: html screenshot]

**What I did?:** I stored all the arrays as I was required to and in python I did this:

```
from querystring_parser import parser 

def index(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        urlEncoded = parser.parse(request.POST.urlencode())
        if length < noOfActionCards:
            appendJsonKey = fullappendJsonKey[length]['']
            appendShowUi = fullappendShowUi[length]['']
            appendHintText = fullappendHintText[length]['']
            .........   
            .........
            dropDownValues = fulldropDownValues[length]
            while i < len(innerArray[length])
            # and so one iterating here...
```

and then saving it on mongodb.